# Store Ctrl+C or Copy values in array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a requirement where I want to stack multiple contents which are to be copied from one place from another. Here the contents to be copied will be plain text.

example,

I want that each and every time I select the bold text in the paragraph below and execute the copy actions, that particular line or text should get stored in an array and whenever I use the paste command all the lines of texts stored in array should get pasted at the destination.

**Note that here the lines are not consecutive, they could be at any
place in the page.**

> **This morning at the Microsoft Ignite conference**, Microsoft Senior
>   Technical Product Manager for SharePoint **Bill Baer took the stage to
>   show off some of the exciting features and improvements** coming to
>   SharePoint 2016.
>
> **With SharePoint 2016,** Microsoft is not killing off the on-premises
>   deployment. **It's no surprise that cloud is where the emphasis is for
>   Microsoft**, but the cloud hasn't killed SharePoint on-premises. It's
>   actually making it better.
>
> **When Microsoft brought SharePoint Online into the cloud, it used
>   SharePoint 2013 as a starting-off point**.From there, it had to manage
>   the beast in largely the same way that IT Professionals have in other
>   environments. Many of the improvements that we're going to get in 2016
>   are a result of Microsoft managing SharePoint 2013 at scale

Now, what I want is that for each and every bold line, when a copy command is executed, that line should get cached or stored in an array resulting an array like this :

copyArray =

> ```
>         [0][This morning at the Microsoft Ignite conference],
>         [1][Bill Baer took the stage to show off some of the exciting  features and improvements],
>
>         [2][With SharePoint 2016,],
>         [3][It's no surprise that cloud is where the emphasis is for Microsoft],
>
>         [4][When Microsoft bought SharePoint online into the cloud, it used SharePoint 2013 as a starting-off point.]
> ```

and finally when executed with the paste command, it should paste the content as below,

> This morning at the Microsoft Ignite conference,Bill Baer took the
>   stage to show off some of the exciting features and improvements With
>   SharePoint 2016, It's no surprise that cloud is where the emphasis is
>   for Microsoft.When Microsoft brought SharePoint Online into the cloud,
>   it used SharePoint 2013 as a starting-off point

it can get pasted in another way if anyone of you can suggest, I just want to facilitate my user such that he does not have to execute copy and paste repeatedly for each and every line he wants to copy-paste. Means the content stored for the copy command should get appended with the text instead of getting overwritten.

Thanks

Comment: I didnt asked for the code, I asked for a suggestion. 

and I guess this is what SO is all about, to solve the code problems.

if this post it violating SO in any way then I will definitely remove it but I want to clear that I didn't asked for any code creation. I just asked for the suggestion, same as posted in the answer below by- Reza Aghaei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a buffer list, `var buffer= new List<string>();`
2. In your copy command add coppied text to buffer,  `buffer.Add(copiedText);` If you need to read text from ClipBoard, use `Clipboard.GetText()`
3. For Paste, use `string.Join('',buffer.ToArray());` to get the result string and put it everywhee you want.